# media software to combine video and audio

Tags: sound, subtitle

I need something that can help me combine my video files with .srt subtitle tracks.
Any ideas? I dont want to use the terminal and command lines, just a simple programme like AutoGK used to be in Windows.

Any ideas what I could use?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try install AutoGK in Ubuntu through Wine. I found these informations, they're a bit old, but maybe they can help you with this:

1. Run "winecfg" and change:

Graphics tab: Emulate a virtual desktop, at least 800x600
Direct3D Vertex Shader Support none

Audio Tab: Hardware Acceleration: Emulation
Check driver emulation.

Applications tab: Windows Version Windows XP

Libraries (I think this is the important one) tab

Add the following overrides:
mfc42u, msvcrt, msvfw32, vorbis

1. Download and installed AutoGK on this machine.
2. Then, copy the DLL's "mfc42u, msvcrt, msvfw32" from a windows machine's system32 directory to the WINE system32 directory.
3. Rename msvcrt.dll MSVCRT.DLL. Probably not necessary, but I know linux is case sensitive (although WINE probably isn't) and the virtualdub error message had a capital msvcrt.

   1. Copy vorbis.dll from the autogk\virtualdubmod directory to the windows\system32 directory.
   2. Type "wine AutoGK.exe" in the AutoGK directory

Troubleshooting: 
If the installer doens't come up (just a blue screen), make sure you have the graphics resolution at least 800x600 in the graphics tab of winecfg

If trying to encode a movie fails on the audio portion (Demuxing, decoding, normalizing, encoding happens in about a second, then fails) it is probably your virtualdub. I fixed this by copying a new msvcrt.dll over to wine, and the vorbis.dll. Try manually running "wine autogk/tools/virtualdubmod.exe" and see if virtualdub comes up. If it doesn't, fix whatever it complains about.

[Source](http://forum.doom9.org/archive/index.php/t-113810.html)

[More info on installing AutoGk through Wine](http://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?t=120180)

There's also some alternatives to AutoGk:

[Handbrake](http://alternativeto.net/software/handbrake/)

[MediaCoder](http://alternativeto.net/software/mediacoder/)

[MakeMKV](http://alternativeto.net/software/makemkv/)

[Lemon Rip](http://alternativeto.net/software/lemon-rip/)

k9copy

acidrip

Answer (score 0):

Mkv file format support include subtitle saparately. It means you don't need encode whole video file.

I recommend [mkvtoolnix](http://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/index.html) for this situation. Open your video file, add sub file then start muxing. Basically it's not different just copying two files into one. Very fast and do not encode audio/video stream.

Pacakge name is mkvtoolnix-gui. Or install latest version from developer's [repo](http://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/downloads.html#ubuntu).

[Video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1dLbhjY3v7Y) - windows version but same with linux one.

Comment: Can you tell me how to set that the output file would be of avi format in MKVTOOLNIX?

Comment: Do you mean keep avi file format?

Comment: Yes, I need them to be .avi so that they could be copied to my nokia phone.